# Запятые: "Утром, за несколько часов до прихода ревизоров, на производство столовой поступило 50 кг яблок"

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно расставить запятые в предложении:
"Утром, за несколько часов до прихода ревизоров, на производство столовой поступило 50 кг яблок"?

Answer (score 1):

Запятые расставлены верно. Когда? Утром. Когда именно? За несколько часов до прихода ревизоров. Выделено уточняющее обстоятельство времени. Но надо заметить, что эти запятые не являются строго обязательными и ставятся на усмотрение автора. 
А что значит *на производство в столовую?* Просто *в столовую* - нельзя?

Comment: Там написано "на производство столовой". Видимо, "столовую" производят из яблок. Может, это "столовая минеральная вода" или что-то подобное? ;-))

Comment: "Производство", имхо, - участок или цех столовой. ну скажем, производство, раздаточная и обеденный зал.  
Смысла подчеркивать эту деталь я тут не вижу никакого, но уж коли автору так важно, то "столовой на производство".

Comment: Вообще-то я пошутила. У @Ларf написано не так, как у автора.

Comment: Прошу прощения за невнимательное прочтение. Но и смайлика у меня никакого не видно...

Answer (score 0):

А я думаю, что стилистически предложение неверно. Как это на производство столовой?